# Constrained optimization problem with the integral

Tags: integration, optimization

I want to maximize the following integral $I = \int_0^\infty  {f\left( {P(x),x} \right){p_X}(x)dx} $ subject to the constraint $\int_0^\infty  {P(x){p_X}(x)dx}  = P_x$, where $p_X(.)$ is a probability distribution function, $P_x$ is a positive real number and $f(.,.)$ is a function. I want to find $P(.)$ as a function of $x$ by using Lagrange Multiplier method. The Lagranrian is 
$$
L = \int_0^\infty  {f\left( {P(x),x} \right){p_X}(x)dx}  - \lambda \left[ {\int_0^\infty  {P(x){p_X}(x)dx}  - P_x} \right].
$$
After differentiate $L$ and set it to zero as follows
$$
\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial P(x)}} = 0,
$$
I obtain $P(x)$ now becomes a function of $x$ and $\lambda$: $P(x) = g(x,\lambda )$. Subtituting this result to the constraint to find $\lambda$ yields the integral $\int_0^\infty  {g(x,\lambda ){p_X}(x)dx} $ diverges. So the equation $\int_0^\infty  {g(x,\lambda ){p_X}(x)dx} = P_x$ cannot be solved.

In this case, what should I do to solve the above optimization problem? Please noted that the goal is to find $P(.)$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: Can you show that your problem has a solution? I doubt so, otherwise you should find the solution by using the Lagrangian.

Comment: Sorry I cannot write the details about my problem here. All I want to ask is are there any methods for such situation like above? For your suggestion, using the Lagrangian and from the equation $\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial P(x)}} = 0$, I can solve $P(x)$ as a specific function of $x$ and $\lambda$ as $P(x)=g(x,\lambda)$. However when I subsitute this to the constraint I get an diverged integral.

Comment: I think that this means that your problem does not possess a solution.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have a solution

Comment: Then, there is a mistake in your computation. If there is a solution, it satisfies the first order conditions (involving the Lagrangian).

Comment: If we take $\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial \lambda}} = 0$, the constraint will be sastified. But not for $\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial P(x)}} = 0$, where I obtain a equation for $P(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first goal is to find those functions $y=y(x)$'s that *extremize* the functional

$$I[P]=\int_0^{\infty} f(y(x),x)p_X(x)dx-\lambda(\int_0^{\infty} y(x)p_X(x)dx-P_x)$$,

for a fixed $f$ and probability distribution $p_X$. We need to compute the derivative

$$\frac{dI}{d\phi}|_{y}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{I[y+\epsilon \phi]-I[y]}{\epsilon}$$,

of $I$ at $y$, considering all small variations $\epsilon \phi$ around $y$. In the spirit of the calculus of variations we should formalize the concept of $\phi(x)$ being a "variation" of $y$. For the terminology and some examples I refer to

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am72.pdf

Let us try to compute $\frac{dI}{d\phi}|_{y}$. Assuming that $f(y,x)$ is differentiable, then we can write

$$f(y+\epsilon \phi,x)-f(y,x)=\langle \nabla (f), h(\epsilon) \rangle + O(\epsilon^2), $$

where we consider the increment $h(\epsilon)=(\epsilon \phi,0)$. $\nabla (f)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $(y,x)$. The functional derivative now becomes (after a bit of algebra)

$$ \frac{dI}{d\phi}|_{y}=\int_0^{\infty} (\frac{\partial f(y(x),x)}{\partial y}-\lambda)\phi(x) p_X(x)dx. $$

for all variations $\phi$ around $y$. Modulo regularity conditions (I am sloppy here!) we arrive at

$$(\frac{\partial f(y(x),x)}{\partial y}-\lambda)p_X(x)=0$$.

A this point you could consider $\frac{\partial f(y(x),x)}{\partial y}-\lambda=0$ and try to solve it w.r.t. $y(x)$ ; however without *extra* hypothesis on $y(x)$ you can not determine the Lagrange multiplier.

ps: are you sure that $f=f(y(x),x)$ and not $f=f(y'(x),y(x),x)$?

Comment: I already arrived at this step and solved $y(x)$. But if I substitute this $y(x)$ to the constraint $\int_0^\infty  {y(x){p_X}(x)dx}  = P_x$, I'll get a diverged integral.

Comment: I see: could you please define $f$ and $p_X$, then?

Comment: $p(x)$ is an exponential distribution function: ${p_X}(x) = \frac{{\exp \left( { - x/\Gamma } \right)}}{\Gamma }$, where $\Gamma > 0$. And $$f\left( {y(x),\,x} \right) = \left( {1 - p} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{y(x)}}{{{P_x}}}x} \right) + p\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{y(x)}}{{{P_x}}}\frac{x}{\xi }} \right) $$, with $\xi > 1$ and $0 \le p \le 1$

Comment: By def. $x>0$. The exponential distribution $p_X$ is always different from zero and we can eliminate it from our "Euler Lagrange eq." for $y(x)$ (please see my answer). With the $f$ you specify I arrive at the equation $\frac{(1-p_X)x}{P_x+xy(x)}+\frac{p_X x}{P_x\xi+xy(x)}=\lambda$ for $y$. Do you confirm it?

Comment: Yes, we can arrive at $$\frac{{1 - p}}{{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{{y(x)}}{{{P_x}}}}} + \frac{p}{{\frac{\xi }{x} + \frac{{y(x)}}{{{P_x}}}}} = {P_x}\lambda.$$

Comment: If $\xi\neq 1$ I can not simplify the above relation to isolate $y(x)$.

Comment: Yes, the point is $\xi \ne 1$. I can solve $y(x)$ as a function of $x$ and $\lambda$ and subtitute this to the constraint. As I mentioned above, we will obtain a diverge integration.

Comment: What do you mean with "I can solve $y(x)$"? $y(x)=..."

Comment: I can get $y$ as a function of $x$ and $\lambda$ as $y(x,\lambda)$. Apply to the constraint I have $\int_0^\infty  {y(x,\lambda ){p_X}(x)dx = {P_x}}$. From this integration, I may find $\lambda$. Unfortunately, that integration diverges.

Comment: Using the above equation it is not possible to isolate $y(x)$. Sorry but I can not see how you arrive at  $y=y(x,\lambda)$ explicitly. Please integrate this information in your original question.

Comment: Let denote $a = {P_x}\lambda $, $z = y(x)/{P_x}$ and $u = 1/x$, we have $$\frac{{1 - p}}{{u + z}} + \frac{p}{{\xi u + z}} = a.$$ After some manipulation we can obtain $$a{z^2} + \left[ {au(1 + \xi ) - 1} \right]z + a\xi {u^2} - [(1 - p)\xi  + p]u = 0$$. Solve this equation for variable $z$ we obtain $z=z(a,u)$, i.e., $y=y(x,\lambda)$.

Comment: That's the point: your solution(s) $y(x)$ can be obtained iff  in the quadratic equation you deduced for $z$ the discriminant is such that $b^2-4ac\geq 0$. Otherwise there exists no real solution. The discriminant is a function of  $\lambda$, $\xi$, $u$ and $p_X$ ($P_x$ is fixed).